# Read Full Query parameter String in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Is there a way for me to read the entire query string in the GET API? Since there can be a variable number of parameters I am already looking at using this

```
public void createUser(@RequestParam(required=false) Map<String,String> qparams) {
}
```

But I want to read the entire query string as well.

The reason being one of the parameters here is an HMAC which is calculated on the entire string. and we are using that HMAC for cross verification.

We have deep integration with third-party software. The issue here is that the third-party software can make a change to their API at any point in time.

Comment: You already answered you question: `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params`. I don't think you need the `required` attribute because for the given case you don't send anything, you would get an empty map.

Comment: @x80486 I need the entire string as well as the query params list. The entire string to calculate the HMAC, and the individual parameters to perform other operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

```
@GetMapping("/test1")
void endpoint1(HttpServletRequest req) {
    var qs = req.getQueryString()  //returns the entire string
    qs.split("&") //split to get the individual parameters
}
```